# how to edit the custom shape of te bones in blenrig

Tags: rigging

In the BlenRig Add-on, I need to edit the custom bone shapes for the controls. I can't find the widget shapes that the controls refer to. Any Help pleas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the mesh objects that BlenRig uses for custom bone shapes on layer 20.

[image: custom shapes]